How to do find and replace within the Snowflake online editor on macOS?
In the editor we can use CMD-F to find text.  What is the shortcut to do find and replace? I have tried a number of things: most of these are swallowed/used by chrome itself:
CMD-R
CMD-OPTF
CMD-H
Is there any shortcut that works?

replace: Ctrl + ⇧ + H

Thanks - if you want to make answer please do.  I also could have used CMD-shift-/ to show shortcuts (but forgot about that)

Find and replace in Snowsight

@LukaszSzozda. I upvoted your answer there.

btw for macOS users it is CMD-shift-H
